android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
I am trying to build my Android application in AndroidStudio but I am getting this error:
ERROR: U:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-99:19: AAPT: error: attribute android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback not found.

(drive U: is pointing to my user home directory).
Any idea anyone what this BS message is supposed to mean?
I googled left and right but the only thing I found re. android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback was that one should have a property android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" defined in the application element.
Both, the application I am trying to build as well as a self-created library .aar-file that I am using do have that property specified and set to true in their respective AndroidManifest.xml-file's application element.
So, why can this then not be found? And where else, if not there is it supposed to be found then? Or what else is this error message trying to convey to me?

What is your compileSdk in your build.gradle?

@ianhanniballake compileSdk 33. Meanwhile I seem to have fixed that by not adding but rather removing the line android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" both from my application as well as from my library that I am using. Don't know how that line ended up there in the first place. I guess it had been added either during the creation of the project (unlikely) or one of the automatic project upgrades after a recent AndroidStudio update (more likely).

android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback was added as part of Android 14 (API 34) to support the Predictive Back Gesture as the flag that allows you to opt-in to the predictive back gesture.
Therefore to use android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback, you need to have a compileSdk of at least 34 - the API level that it was introduced.
As explained in the Picking your compileSdk, minSdk, and targetSdk blog post, you should always compile with the latest SDK - this will allow you to iteratively start using those new APIs. Behavior changes related to new versions of Android are only changed by changing your targetSdk, which you can do as a separate step later.

@@ianhanniballake Thanks! That blog-post helped to better understand these setting. They had been rather obscure to me so far... Appreciated!
